# Scala .map() Information Loss (Since return type is same as elements: Set)

Tags: scala

I am using this piece of code to get the weighted sum of a map of elements:

```
val wSum = elements.map(element=>
        weights(element) * values(element))
      .sum
```

While testing, if I pass

```
weights = Map(1 -> 1.0, 2 -> 1.0, 3 -> 1.0)
values = Map(1 -> 0.2, 2 -> 0.6, 3 -> 0.4)
```

It returns 1.2 as expected. On the other hand, if I pass

```
weights = Map(1 -> 1.0, 2 -> 1.0, 3 -> 1.0)
values = Map(1 -> 0.5, 2 -> 0.5, 3 -> 0.5)
```

This returns 0.5. This seems like dangerously wrong, am I missing a commonly used alternative instead?

Comment: If not dibs on the PR unless already raised

Comment: what is the type of `elements`?

Comment: Set also, goofed on the title

Comment: Also before someone chimes in with the "make elements Seq then" I got you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is behaving correctly, so it isn't really wrong, and certainly not dangerously so.

If you are actually trying to compute `weights*values` for each element and then sum the result, there are two common ways of doing this:

The simplest is just

```
elements.toList.map(element=>
    weights(element) * values(element))
  .sum
```

The other option is to compute the sum in one pass using `foldLeft`:

```
elements.foldLeft(0.0){
  case (prev, element) => prev + weights(element) * values(element)
}
```

---

To understand the behaviour in the original code you need to understand what `map` does:

> The `map` method on a collection creates a new collection of the same type by applying a function to each element of the old collection and adding it to the new collection.

The key point is that the collection type is not changed, so any rules that apply to the old collection also apply to the new collection. If the collection is ordered then the ordering is retained. If the collection is self-sorting then the new collection will be sorted. If the collection has set-like properties then duplicate elements will not be added to the new collection.

In this question the problem is made more complicated by using Java classes in Scala code. The behaviour of a Java collection might be different from the Scala behaviour, so the correct approach is to convert all Java collections to Scala collections using `asScala` from `JavaConverters`.

Comment: "certainly not dangerously" unless Java maps are involved

Comment: Accepting this since it shows the ways to avoid your product from randomly popping out blatantly wrong results

Comment: Java is not mentioned in the question, and certainly not Java maps.

Comment: Sorry, but the code is operating correctly and doing exactly what would be expected. If you don't understand what `map` on a `Set` does, then that is not really the fault of the language.

Comment: And everyone uses `asScala` from `JavaConverters` to make sure that they have Scala classes not Java classes.

Comment: Java is directly importable so people directly import it. Weighted sums are used for machine learning so people use them. People use Scala built on legacy Java solutions for their gazillion dollar totally not Orwellian surveillance suites. And they import Java without some fancy function since it is not enforced. And at the end, their gazillion dollar solution is giving completely wrong results, getting wronger based on the specific distribution of your data. Because Set[].map is working exactly as it is supposed to. On their shamelessly direct imported Java HashMaps

Comment: Fortunately this coding error gets caught very quickly by the unit tests, so in the end it is just the developer's pride that suffers.

Comment: "Haha plebian git gud" - in response to language quirk that has no mathematical or practical basis besides sentiment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195213/discussion-between-victor-s-and-tim).

Answer (score 1):

So mapping over a set returns a set. Seems logical to me. IIRC, preserving return type of the original collection was a big part of scala collections library. Your immediate fix would be to call `elements.toSeq` before mapping.

However, I'd go with a case class to encapsulate Elements:

```
case class Element(weight: Double, value: Double) {
  def weightedValue = weight * value
}

val elements = Map(1 -> Element(1.0, 0.5), 2 -> Element(1.0, 0.5))

elements.values.map(_.weightedValue).sum
```

Answer (score 0):

The resulting Set from the Set.map() call is collapsing repeated values, like Sets are supposed to do...

Comment: And the award goes to... This is why I put the elements type on the title. Java represents Map keysets as well, key Sets so changing the element type does not help when your use case involves Java maps. So is there anything other than .map for my use case or is someone's product somewhere else popping out garbage as we speak?